# Duplicate methods in parent and child forms

Tags: c#, winforms

> Environment: Visual Studio 2008, C#, SQL Server, Windows development, Multiuser, New Developer

I have a method in `form A` that I use to display textbox information there.

Also I have a button that displays another form when clicked (form B).

`Form B` is created with `frm.ShowDialog();`

`Form B` has the same textboxes on it with the same names, they are identical (*copied and pasted from form A*)

I want to use the method in Form A to display the information in `Form B`, rather than copying and pasting the method from `form A` into `form B`

I made the method in `form A` public and called it from `from B` but nothing displays in `form B`'s textboxes.  Why?  I don't get any errors.

Should I keep it simple and put a copy of `form A`'s method in Form B instead of calling the method in `form A` from `form B`?  That's the only way I can get it to work.

---

Form A is for displaying customer information, Form B is for editing customer information.

I'm passing and returning information between the forms and that's all working.

The forms are not identical, i.e.,  form B doesn't have textbox for the customer's notes, they are edited in a separate form.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Methods from `Form A` won't work in `Form B` since `controls` are different in both forms. Put some code in your question which might help us to create generic method for same logic.

Answer (score 2):

you should use an info class and retrieve data from it both in form A and form B 
don't use duplicate code, just use another class for logic \ info.

You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 0):

Make a model class whose members represent the data to be shown in both forms. In visual studio 2008 I believe there is support to create a project data source based on an object. Create the data source from your model class. Then, in both forms, add a binding source. Set the data type for the source to be the project data source. Then, the designer will let you select bindings for each control from the binding source. Finally, in the form's constructor, accept a model class instance, and set the binding source's data source to be that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have the same textboxes with same names when you call formA you are just changing the instance of formA which means only the textboxes in formA are changed.

You have to understand that every class has its own instance separate from the other.

That does not mean though that you cannot access formB textboxes in formA. I can see that you want to consolidate; if I'm not mistaken what you have in formA method is something like:

```
public void methodA(Customer customer)
{
textboxName = customer.Name;
textboxAddress = customer.Address;
}
```

If you dont want to duplicate this then the other approach that I can think of is:

1.) Create an interface for all the duplicate properties.

```
public interface ICustomerForm
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    string Address {get; set;}
}
```

2.) Have the 2 forms implement the interface.

```
public class FormA : Form, ICustomerForm
{
   public string Name
   {
      get
      {
         return _textBoxName.Text;
      }
      set
      {
         _textBoxName.Text = value;
      }
   }
```

}

Do the same for formB

3.) Create a static helper class where you just pass the customer class. e.g:

```
public static class FormHelper
{
    public static UpdateCustomerInfo(ICustomerForm form, Customer customer)
    {
        form.Name = customer.Name;
        form.Address = customer.Address;
    }
}
```

4.) In your two forms just call the helper class and pass itself as the first parameter and the customer class as the second parameter.
    //Method in formA
    public void formA()
    {
        FormHelper.UpdateCustomerInfo(this, customer);
    }

```
//Method in formB
public void formB()
{
    FormHelper.UpdateCustomerInfo(this, customer);
}
```

This way you just have one line of code in your forms and the setting of info is on the consolidated helper class.